# ¿Cómo se configura un botón para añadir imágenes utilizando php?

Tags: php, html

Utilicé una plantilla de Bootstrap con un formulario sencillo y ya configurado previamente. Le añadí un botón para que el usuario pueda añadir archivos (Quisiera que únicamente pudieran mandar archivos jpg, png y pdf para evitar virus), pero no conozco bien acerca de php así que no pude configurarlo, lo dejé funcionando para el anterior formulario que solamente es "Nombre, Email, Teléfono, Mensaje". Quisiera que ese botón de "Añadir imágenes" funcionara  correctamente, me gustaría que al usuario le saliera cuando sus imágenes ya están cargadas (Que abajo del botón salga por ejemplo: archivo1.jpg, archivo2.jpg, etc." Y obviamente lo más importante, al momento de dar "Enviar" me lleguen las imágenes al correo que configuré en el archivo php. Ya que de momento sólamente me llega "Nombre, Email, Teléfono, Mensaje".

Adjunto el código en HTML del formulario:

```
 <form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Su Nombre*" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte su nombre">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Su Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte su email.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Su teléfono *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte un teléfono válido.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Características de su vehículo *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Porfavor inserte su mensaje."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
               <!--<div class="primerBoton btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton">
                <span class="segundoBoton">AÑADIR IMÁGENES</span>
                <input name="files[]" id="imagenes" type="file" placeholder="imágenes" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte archivos JPG o PNG." multiple  class="btn tercerBoton btn-xl">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>-->
            </div> 
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
              <div id="success"></div>
              <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Asímismo, quiero reiterar que sí funciona correctamente pero sin que se manden las imágenes, adjunto ahora el código PHP, ojalá alguien me pudiera apoyar con el código correcto porque he investigado mucho al respecto pero todos los formularios son diferentes y este en particular lo veo muy extraño, no sé si son arrays o qué pasa pero la sintaxis es muy rara.

```
<?php
// Campos vacíos
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Email
$to = 'autoparteselromeral@hotmail.com';
$email_subject = "Contacto de compra de autos:  $name";
$email_body = "Ha recibido un mensaje.\n\n"."Estos son los detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nTel: $phone\n\nMensaje:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noresponder@chocadosmexico.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Lo que más me interesa es que se manden las imágenes a mi correo con el archivo php, ya en segunda me gustaría que el usuario vea que sus archivos se han cargado, pero bueno, paso a pasito. 
¡Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Por si cambias de opinion respecto a los tipos de archivo que quieres que suba el usuario, solo basta con especificar las extensiones de archivos que pueden ser aceptados en el input.

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif, .jpeg">
```

Comment: Gracias amigazo, mi problema más grande es hacer que se manden a mi correo los archivos en el formulario PHP